# Error on Backpressed Video Gallery

Tags: java, android

I have a module which selects a video from gallery then put it to videoview. But when I try to click my Gallery then back pressed, it crashes my application and point me to this code. (the code line with an arrow)

Here's my code.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

--->    Uri filePath = data.getData();

    path = filePath+"";
    if (requestCode == RECORD_VIDEO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
        ivVideo.setVideoPath(path);
        ivVideo.setMediaController(new android.widget.MediaController(getActivity()));
        ivVideo.requestFocus();
        ivVideo.start();
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

    }

}
```

Here's the onClickListener.

```
ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),RECORD_VIDEO);

    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried a condition that if filepath is null it will pop up a message.. 

still error though.

Comment: post error log.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.christian.rescueme2.VideoFragment.onActivityResult(VideoFragment.java:71)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!!

I just placed the Uri inside the condition..

haha.. I solved my own question.. Thanks guys for trying to help :)

```
if (requestCode == RECORD_VIDEO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri filePath = data.getData();

            path = filePath+"";

            ivVideo.setVideoPath(path);
            ivVideo.setMediaController(new android.widget.MediaController(getActivity()));
            ivVideo.requestFocus();
            ivVideo.start();
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check  if the data is null inside onActivityResult()

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(data!=null){
    // Your code
  }
}
```